# Jquery - Create dynamic name selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been playing with this for the last hour, but just cant get it to work.

I have a reactJS component, that renders a grid. After the grid is rendered I need to do some DOM work on the component.

There are some checkboxes that need to be checked. After the DOM is available if I run this in console:

```
$('[name="checkbox0"]').prop('checked', true);
```

It works great.

I need to iterate my objects, and based on condition check it or not.

My question is how to make the selector dynamic? How do I make checkbox0 dynamic, so I can set it to checkbox1, checkbox5... etc.

This is my latest attempt to solve the issue, and it did not work:

```
this.state.rows.forEach(function (index, key, value){
        var test = "'[name=" + "checkbox" + key + "]'" ;

        if(index.selected){
            //$('[name="checkbox0"]').prop('checked', true);
            $(test).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `var test = '[name="checkbox' + key + '"]' ;` - your selector format is wrong

Comment: That did the trick. Please make an answer so I can accept it :) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use an attribute selector, but the syntax is way off in the dynamic string

```
var test = '[name="checkbox' + key + '"]'
```

You are wrapping the entire string with a `""` where it should have only for the attribute value